# outlet collection removefromsuperview

Tags: uiview, ios8, xib

I have an outlet collection, and tried to remove one of the views by accessing it from the collection array and calling removefromsuperview. This ended up removing all the views that were attached to the collection from the interface builder. Any help would be appreciated!

```
assignments.removeAtIndex(i).removeFromSuperview()
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pglhob9uyflv8kn/ass.tiff?dl=0

Comment: Please post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`assignments.removeAtIndex(i).removeFromSuperview()` you're first removing an object from the assignments array, and then you're calling `removeFromSuperview` on the whole array.

All it looks like you should have to do is `assignments[i].removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: i also wanted to to remove it from the array, and even if I just removefromsuperview, all the views are still removed